# Lovasz Softmax loss explanation

Tags: deep-learning, loss-function, image-segmentation

I would like to use Lovasz softmax for foreground background semantic segmentation because of its ability to improve segmentation with Jaccard index according to paper.

I got the idea that its a convex surrogate loss function for Jaccard loss using lovasz extension.

From the code and explanation from [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/64276/125019), ultimately loss can be represented as weighted linear combination of function "g(m)"(Jaccard grad) with weights "m" is hinge loss error for corresponding pixel as shown in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.08790) as well.

$$\text{loss}(F)=\overline{\Delta_{J_1}}(m(F))$$

where

$$\overline{\Delta}:m \in \Bbb{R}^p \mapsto \sum \limits_{i=1}^p m_ig_i(m)$$

$with \ g_i(m) = \Delta (\{\pi_1,...,\pi_i \}) - \Delta (\{\pi_1,...,\pi_{i-1} \}),$

$\pi \ being \ a \ permutation \ ordering \ the \ components \ of \ m \ in \ decreasing \ order,$

$i.e. \ x_{\pi_{1}} \ge x_{\pi_{2}} \ ... \ge x_{\pi_{p}}$

My question:

1. Is my understanding correct?
2. In the calculation of Jaccard grad in the [code](https://github.com/bermanmaxim/LovaszSoftmax/blob/master/tensorflow/lovasz_losses_tf.py) how does `gts - tf.cumsum(gt_sorted)` give intersection and `gts + tf.cumsum(1. - gt_sorted)` give a union calculation?
3. Can someone give a more intuitive explanation?

Thank you in advance.